# GTmetrix waterfall disorder optimization for JS website (Angular)

Tags: angular, performance, optimization, gtmetrix

I'm using GTmetrix to check my website performance and did a lot of changes as suggested by GTMetrix as well.

Now I am stuck somewhere, Attached screenshot for reference.[image]

I am not able to understand why the waterfall of GTMetrix is in disorder (Why not all calls are in line). Also, there are a lot of URL's being called which does not exist in codebase like `tr.snapchat.com` etc. can someone please point how can I avoid these calls or optimize more or debug it?

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to understand why the waterfall of GTMetrix is in disorder (Why not all calls are in line).

That is because you're not using http2 protocol. Enable http2 on server to fetch results in parallel and gain some load improvements.

> Also, there are a lot of URL's being called which does not exist in codebase like tr.snapchat.com etc. can someone please point how can I avoid these calls or optimize more or debug it?

Those requests comes from 3rd party scripts that you'r using. E.g. hotjar, fbpixel etc.

Add async pipe to those script loading to gain some load improvements too.

Comment: Hey, I am already using the async pipe. But I have not added any 3rd party script for Snapchat still I can see request from snapchat, why so? I'll check about http2.

Comment: you can't really optimize those requests cause those are coming from 3rd party libs you're using and those are firing that requests... so no point in that.

Comment: ok, After reading I found HTTP2's first paint is a bit lower than that of using HTTPS also few drawbacks with negligible performance improvements.

Comment: it really depends on a lot of factors if it's gonna improve your performances. You have to find your best approach on that one. I just answered your questions.